# app-only calls fail on term store change on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store, multi-tenancy

Does SharePoint allow app-only access to Term Store?
I'm trying to update Term Store via app-only access. Is this possible?
Its working with user delegation, because user can be added to Term Store administrators in SharePoint admin panel. However I cannot find a way to add my Service Principal (created by consent framework because application is Multi tenant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, It is not possible to update the Term Store with app-only permission. You must use user credentials that have Term Store Administrator rights.

Even though there is a permission scope for this, it evidently doesn't do anything. Sorry I don't have a link for reference.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt210897.aspx#sectionSection0)

Comment: The link is here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt210897.aspx#sectionSection0

Comment: Ah this is really disappointing. I'll have to improvise somehow. Thank you for fast answer.